# How can I put an image on a Matlab uicontrol button?

Tags: html, matlab, icons, uicontrol, matlab-gui

I have Matlab 2019b, GUI Layout Toolbox 2.3.4 and t all runs on MacOs 14 Mojave.

I want to create button in in a UI that have icons/images instead of text. I have seen here:

https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/html-support-in-matlab-uicomponents/

that it is supposed to be possible to use HTML to render the button contents.

So - I try this sample code:

```
figure('MenuBar','none','Name','GUI-TEST','NumberTitle','off','Position',[200,200,140,90]);
push_btn = uicontrol('Style','PushButton','String','Push','Position',[30,60,80,20],...
  'CallBack','disp(''You are pressed a push button'')');
close_btn = uicontrol('Style','PushButton','String','Close','Position',[30,5,80,50],...
    'CallBack','close');
icon_file = fullfile(pwd, 'close.png')
str = ['<html><img src="file://' icon_file '"></html>']
set(close_btn,'String',str);
```

but it leaves me with an empty button.

[image]

If I deliberately use a filename that does not correspond to an existing file, I see a broken image icon:

[image]

So I am reasonably sure that the basic syntax and file path stuff is correct but the image does not get rendered in the button.

Is there something else I need to do to make this work or is it all just part of Matlab's overwhelming strangeness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to put an image on a uicontrol (and specifically a button), is to use the `CData` property,

```
im_orig = imread(icon_file);  % Needs to be true color, i.e. MxNx3
im_sized = imresize(im_orig,[80,50]); % size of the button
% str = ['<html><img src="file://' icon_file '"></html>'];
% set(close_btn,'String',str);
set(close_btn,'CData',im_sized);
```

Comment: Thank you.

Yes, that works nicely.

Do you know why the HTML business fails to render the image?